# Converting pandas df containing rownames, columnnames and frequency to Term Document Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn, nltk

I have a pandas df in the following format:
 Input :

```
 Freq Document  TermId
  3     A      112
  5     A      055
  1     C      003
  4     D      001
  2     B      003
  1     D      089
```

I want to convert this dataframe to a term document matrix (preferably another pandas df) . What will be the most efficient way of achieving this?

Ex output:

```
Term/Document  A  B  C  D
    001        0  0  0  4
    003        0  2  1  0
    055        5  0  0  0
    089        0  0  0  1
    112        3  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the desired DataFrame has an index whose labels are from `df['TermId']` and whose column labels are from `df['Document']`. Whenever the index and column labels come from columns of `df`, think about using [`df.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) (or [`df.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) if aggregation is needed):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Document': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'D'],
                   'Freq': ['3', '5', '1', '4', '2', '1'],
                   'TermId': ['112', '055', '003', '001', '003', '089']})
result = df.pivot(index='TermId', columns='Document', values='Freq').fillna(0)
print(result)
```

yields

```
Document  A  B  C  D
TermId              
001       0  0  0  4
003       0  2  1  0
055       5  0  0  0
089       0  0  0  1
112       3  0  0  0
```

Comment: thanks! df.pivot_table worked for me as the TermId column in original df had duplicates